# How to compare two macros containing Cyrillic?

Tags: conditionals, cyrillic, ukrainian

Short question is:
**How to compare two macros containing Cyrillic?**

It is not difficult to compare two strings with `\ifx` for Latin strings

```
\def\contentsnameinlanguage{Contents}
\ifx\contentsname\contentsnameinlanguage 1 \else 0 \fi % 1
```

But what if I want to do the same for Cyrillic strings?

```
\def\contentsnameinlanguage{Зміст}
\ifx\contentsname\contentsnameinlanguage 1 \else 0 \fi %
```

I would like to receive 1 in this case too.

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ukrainian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{english}
\def\contentsnameinlanguage{Contents}
\ifx\contentsname\contentsnameinlanguage 1 \else 0 \fi % 1

\meaning\contentsname

\selectlanguage{ukrainian}
\def\contentsnameinlanguage{Зміст}
\ifx\contentsname\contentsnameinlanguage 1 \else 0 \fi % 0

\expandafter\meaning\contentsname

\end{document}
```

Comment: The problem of your comparison is, that the first definition of `\contentsname` after the `\selectlanguage{ukrainian}` is `{\cyr \CYRZ \cyrm \cyrii \cyrs \cyrt }` and not `Зміст`.

Comment: @Skillmon I realised that

Comment: Comparing against `\def\contentsnameinlanguage{{\cyr\CYRZ\cyrm\cyrii\cyrs\cyrt}}` would work. The tokens simply don't match.

Comment: You can make the compare with `\ifx` work with `\edef\contentsnameinlanguage{{\cyrЗміст}}` compared against `\edef\contentsnameedef{\contentsname}` if that's better for you.

Comment: @Skillmon are you sure?

Comment: Why do you even need that comparison? There might be much better ways than those ugly workarounds to achieve what you intend to do (well, as long as nobody except you knows what you want to achieve no one can say for sure).